# Loop Through Each Print Page in Worksheet with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, printing, footer

In VBA, how do you loop through each printable page of each worksheet in a workbook and create unique footers? I want to put "Page # of Numpages" throughout my workbook. I have multiple worksheets and each worksheet has multiple print pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub AddPageNumbersToFooters()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim numPages as Integer
    numPages = 0

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.PageSetup
            .RightFooter = "Page &P+" & CStr(numPages) & " of "
            numPages = numPages + .Pages.Count
        End With
    Next wsTolStack

    For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.PageSetup
            .RightFooter = .RightFooter & CStr(numPages)
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```